# отменить зум кластера при клике gmap

Tags: кластер, cluster

Всем привет! Как отменить зум при клике на кластер в Google Maps API JS?
Так же надо получить информацию о метках, которые входят в нажатый кластер.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Нужно отредактировать markerclusterer.js, а именно строку 
this.zoomOnClick_ = true;

Получить данные маркеров кластера при клике эвентом:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
        console.log(cluster.getMarkers());
    });
```